# Apply filters in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbee to angular and have this filter to translate the text (localization) which works well in my html/view:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-link" value="{{'weeklyOrdersPage.reposting' | translate}}" ng-click="sortBy('reposting')" />
```

What this does is to take the value from one resource file and display text and it works very well.

Now, I need to do something similar in controller where I am rendering a google map using javascript api. I need to set the text of the marker based on the language i choose. I tried this and it didn't work:

```
var markerConter = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' +
                                       '<div><b>' + $filter('translate')("{{'weeklyOrdersPage.panelId'}}") + ': </b>' + panel.id + '</div>' +
                                       '<div><b>' + $filter('translate')("{{'weeklyOrdersPage.panelClassification'}}") + ': </b>' + panel.panelClassification + '</div>' +
                                       '<div><b>' + $filter('translate')('{{weeklyOrdersPage.quality}}') + ': </b>' + panel.format + '</div>'
                    '</div>';
```

Any pointers on how to move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `{{}}` when writing code in `controller`

```
$filter('translate')('weeklyOrdersPage.panelId')
$filter('translate')('weeklyOrdersPage.panelClassification')
$filter('translate')('weeklyOrdersPage.quality')
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks....works like a charm. Only thing i had to do was to include quotes around each key.